# Getting error while adding these dependencies in app/build.gradle file in android

Tags: android, dependencies, material-design

I want to use the TabLayout with ViewPager in android.
For that I am adding this `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'` in the dependencies section of  `app/gradle.build` file.

[This is the state of my dependency section before adding `'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGWkq.png)

[This is the state of my dependency section after adding `'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01'`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqlbU.png)

After adding `com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha01` dependency, `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0` gives error.

I don't have any idea why this is happening...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0
```

Update with Andrioidx library.

Migrate your project with android to androidx then you able to add material dependencies.

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

Comment: Yahh. Thank You. It works. We just need to go in the Refactor Tab in Android Studio and Click on Migrate to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

clean the project and adding these library then syn the project

```
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```